# corona rough surface : friction

Tags: physics, coronasdk, surface

I want to make a rough surface, which when a ball roll over it, the ball will stop very quick. (like a heavy steel ball rolling on some sand)

I have try to set friction to 1.0 for both the ball and the surface, and I have tried to set higher density for both, but it just doesn't seem like what I want, the ball will stop only if it hit something, else, it will just keep rolling at the surface. (although is slow, but I want it stop like within 2sec).

Comment: What other parameters you can change? I suppose changing something like "viscosity" or "slippery" could help.

Comment: I do not know corona. How high can you set `friction`? There is no reason in physics for it to be limited to 1.0. As you vary this parameter, do you see the behavior of the ball change? If not, then it is the wrong parameter (there is more than one kind of friction).

Comment: i have refer to the documentation but didn't anything else that i can use, in documentation it tell that default friction is 0.3, set to 1.0 would be strong friction.

Comment: Is `friction` static, dynamic or rolling friction?

Comment: rolling friction, anyway i have found a way to decrease the speed and stop the rolling ball by my control. :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I set the floor to have a ridiculously high friction and my character too but it never stops. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

To quote from:
http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/game-edition-physics-bodies

"friction may be any non-negative value; a value of 0 means no friction and 1.0 means fairly strong friction. The default value is 0.3."

set it to 100, see what happens